# How to use first function's return value in second function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, function

This is my code. In the first def function, I made it return column_choose, and I wanna use column_choose's value in second def function(get_data_list). What can I do? I have tried many times. But IDLE always show:global name 'column_choose' is not defined.

How to use column_choose's value in second function?
By the way, I use python 3.2

```
def get_column_number():
while True:
    column_choose = input('What column:')
    if column_choose == '1' or column_choose == '2' or column_choose == '3' or column_choose == '4' or column_choose == '5' or column_choose == '6':
        column_choose = int(column_choose)
        return column_choose
        break
    else:
        print('bad column number, try again')

def get_data_list(column_number):
new_column_number = column_number.split(',')
date_column = new_column_number[0]
choose_column = new_column_number[column_choose-1]

return result

def main():
#Call get_input_descriptor
get_input_descriptor()
#Call get_column_number
get_column_number()

file_obj = open("table.csv", "r")
for column_number in file_obj:
    column_number = (column_number.strip())
    result = get_data_list(column_number)
    print(result)

file_obj.close()
main()
```

Comment: You should edit your code, the indent is error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign column number to a variable.  Also, you don't need the `break` statement since you're putting it after a return.

```
#Call get_column_number
column_num = get_column_number()
```

Also, I'm not sure you're writing the code correctly. The line
`for column_number in file obj:` is iterating through your csv file.  If you're trying to access a specific column, you could do this:

```
content = ''
file_obj = open('table.csv','r')
content = fle_obj.split(',')
print(content[column_number])
```

Comment: How to assign column number to a variable? It is a local variable now.

Comment: Thanks dude! I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indent format is error?
2. You have use `return` in your `get_column_number` function, so you don't need to use `break` after it
3. The function `get_column_number` return a variable, so you can use it assign to a variable

   Just like:

   ```
   var = get_column_number()
   ```

   and then use var variable
4. If you want it to be a global variable, you can use `global`

I think you need to read a python book to master the basic knownledge